# How can I display a tuple field from a model to a template in Django?

Tags: python, django, tuples, field

I'm pretty new to Django here guys so go easy on me please...

Let me elaborate on what the title question says. Basically I have this model....

```
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Digital Media'

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('icon_sets', 'Icon Sets'),
        ('brand_logos', 'Brand Logos'),
        ('web_banners', 'Web Banners')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    SIZE_CHOICES = (
        ('1616', '16 x 16 pixels'),
        ('3232', '32 x 32 pixels'),
        ('6464', '64 x 64 pixels'),
        ('128128', '128 x 128 pixels'),
        ('256256', '256 x 256 pixels')
    )
    sizes = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SIZE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this view ...

```
def product_detail(request, product_id):
    """ A view to show individual product details """

    print_media = Print_Media.objects.all()
    digital_media = Digital_Media.objects.all()

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)

    print(product, print_media, digital_media)
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'print_media': print_media,
        'digital_media': digital_media,
    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_detail.html', context)
```

So "IF" all is ok with the above code, can someone help me to get the field "sizes" from the model onto a template as I'm having trouble doing this on my own - here is what I have tried so far...

```
{% with product.is_print_media as p %}
    {% if p %}
        <div class="col-12">
            {{ p.sizes }}
            <p><strong>Size:</strong></p>
            <select class="form-control rounded-0 w-50" name="product_size" id="id_product_size">
                <option value="{{ p.sizes }}"></option>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="" selected></option>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Any help with this is much appreciated  :)

Again - go easy on the newbie.....

Comment: What do you want to show? The value of `sizes`  field or do you want iterate over `SIZE_CHOICES`? Confused about `<option> </option>`

Answer (score 0):

If **SIZE_CHOICES** is attribute of model `Print_Media` you can access it us **`p.SIZE_CHOICES`** in template.

Otherwise, provide it as `context` in your view `Digital_Media.SIZE_CHOICES`:

```
def product_detail(request, product_id):
    """ A view to show individual product details """

    print_media = Print_Media.objects.all()
    digital_media = Digital_Media.objects.all()

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)

    print(product, print_media, digital_media)
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'print_media': print_media,
        'digital_media': digital_media,
        'category_choices': Digital_Media.CATEGORY_CHOICES
        'size_choices': Digital_Media.SIZE_CHOICES
    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_detail.html', context)
```

In template `size_choices` or `p.SIZE_CHOICES`.
Assuming that you used `size_choices`:

```
{% with product.is_print_media as p %}
    {% if p %}
        <div class="col-12">
            {{ p.sizes }}
            <p><strong>Size:</strong></p>
            <section class="mt-20">
                <select class="form-control rounded-0 w-50" name="product_size" id="id_product_size_{{ p.pk }}">
                {% for size in size_choices %}
                <option value="{{ item.0 }}" {% if size.0 == p.sizes %}selected{% endif %}>{{ item.1 }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: how do i get that info to the template?

Comment: @JinxCat, i edited my answer: `{% for size in size_choices %} {% endfor %}`.

Comment: @JinxCat, If **SIZE_CHOICES** is attribute of model `Print_Media` you can access it us **`p.SIZE_CHOICES`** in template.

Answer (score 0):

In django templates , choices will be showing like this. That will return the readable value for the field,

> {{ p.get_sizes_display }}.

Vote up, if this one helps you !!!

Comment: Thanks @sree - I tried {{ p.size_choices }}  but nothing happened - what am i doing wrongly?

Comment: I did try to Vote Up but I dont have the reputation points yet as I'm only new...soz!

Comment: its not  {{ p.size_choices }} , its {{ p.get_sizes_display }}. change choices to display..

Answer (score 0):

For every field that has choices set, the object will have a get_FOO_display() method, where FOO is the name of the field. This method returns the “human-readable” value of the field.
so try:

```
{{p.get_sizes_display}}
```

for another example:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
```

we can access Small, Medium and Large in templates with (p as a Person):

```
{{p.get_shirt_size_display}}
```